# The new Logitech StreamCam has stopped working on a specific computer after few month

Tags: webcam, video-streaming, camera, ubuntu-20.04, logitech-webcam

There is a new Logitech StreamCam web camera purchased few month ago. It was working perfect without any issues for couple of month, but since the last week it started glitching and finally stopped working at all. When I connect the same web camera to another computer or a laptop - it works fine. Thant means that the webcamera itself is completely fine.

I have tried to switch the USB ports - no change, also I have running both: windows and ubuntu on that computer - on both operating systems the web camera is not working. This makes me feel really confused on what is going on. Maybe that is some kind of a hacker attack?

I'm sure that the web camera is working fine, because when I connect it to other devices - it functions. I have also switched the USB ports and operating systems on the same PC - nothing helps. It was working perfect for a while (like couple of month).

The web camera is Logitech StreamCam https://www.logitech.com/en-us/products/webcams/streamcam.960-001289.html

The version of the ubuntu is 20.04 with latest updates
The version of the Windows OS is 10 with latest service packs and updates installed.

Please help me to understand what is going on and why it fails, or at least in which direction to investigate this as this behaviour makes me really confused, I'm out of ideas.